# application with angularjs is not working

Tags: angularjs

this is my index.htlm

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
  <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  <script src="js/userController.js"></script>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
  </head>
  <body ng-controller="myCtrl">
    My Name is  {{firstName}}+{{lastName}}
    <p ng-bind-html="firstName"></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

I wrote some codes for angular app and angular controller

```
"use strict"
var app=angular.module('myApp',[]);
```

and this is my angular controller

```
app.controller('myCtrl',function ($scope) {
    $scope.firstName="Mehman";
    $scope.lastName="Hummetli";
});
```

Please help me how can i sole that problem. the result is like that

```
My Name is {{firstName}}+{{lastName}}
```

Comment: it just give me like that {{firstName}}+{{lastName}} but i need Mehman Hummetli instead of that

Comment: Have you added Angular to index.html?

Comment: <script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="js/userController.js"></script>

Comment: I only added that if you mean it?

Comment: Did you add the angular framework scripts? userController.js and app.js seem to be your files but not the ones required for running angular as itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the `angular.js` library to the page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
  <head>
    <script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/userController.js"></script>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
  </head>
  <body ng-controller="myCtrl">
    My Name is  {{firstName}}+{{lastName}}
    <p ng-bind="firstName"></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

The [DEMO on PLNKR](https://plnkr.co/edit/49yv7EBigLkyjcda4Q8A?p=preview)

Also it is better to place `<script>` elements inside either the `<head>` or `<body>` element.

From the Docs:

> ## HTML `<html>` element
>
> > **Permitted content:**   One `<head>` element, followed by one `<body>` element.
>
> — [MDN HTML Element Reference - `<html>` Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/html)

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH. I didnt inserted library to my project. It was work after insert library to my html.

Comment: Do i must insert that library to my all html if i want use angular?

Comment: The AngularJS framework compiles the HTML client-side in the browser. Its JavaScript library needs to be loaded either from your server or a CDN.